# site is responsive in desktop browser but not on iphone/ipad

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have this site that i am making responsive. I have been testing the responsiveness in the desktop browser and everything resizes and seems to work just fine. The problem arises when i test on my iphone and ipad where it does not work. I have this in my head as well:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

This is the site im working on: http://klaraklok.stiankilaas.com/.

Anyone know what the reason might be?

Appreciate the help!

Stian.

Comment: Two things: 1) Create  JSFiddle which isolates the problem. 2) What does not work?

Comment: Is it ok if you run http://84.202.201.162/klaraklok/ ???

Comment: wow, yep it works when i run it with the ip address! thanks:) but why is it not working with the when not using the ip? please excuse my lack of knowledge on this area.

Comment: @Stinis87 it is all in the `frame`

Comment: what do you mean by its all in the frame marcel?